# Find the number of occurrences of strings separated by comma and output the string

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am doing an entity disambiguation project, and I have a dataframe of authors of the same name, with the following column: `author ID` and `coauthor names`.

I need to find the number collaboration between an author, identified by author ID, and all of his/her coauthors that he/she has ever worked with.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
author.ID             coauthor.names
   1                  J Smith, A Greer
   1                  J Adams, J Smith
   2                  D Richardson, J Smith
```

I want the output to be:

```
author.ID     coauthor.name     collaboration.times
   1             J Smith                2
   1             J Adams                1
   1             A Greer                1
   2             D Richardson           1
   2             J Smith                1
```

I have tried combining all coauthors (separated by a comma) of author with a specific author ID into one big string, and I am about to use `str_count` from `stringr` package on this giant string, but I don't know if I am on the right track to solving this problem.

Is there a more efficient or elegant way to attack this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with data like this:

```
mydf <- structure(list(author.ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), coauthor.names = c("J Smith, A Greer", 
    "J Adams, J Smith", "D Richardson, J Smith")), .Names = c("author.ID", 
    "coauthor.names"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
mydf
##   author.ID        coauthor.names
## 1         1      J Smith, A Greer
## 2         1      J Adams, J Smith
## 3         2 D Richardson, J Smith
```

... you can try `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package and then aggregate with `.N` from "data.table":

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, "coauthor.names", ",", "long")[
  , list(collaboaration.times = .N), .(author.ID, coauthor.names)][]
#    author.ID coauthor.names collaboaration.times
# 1:         1        J Smith                    2
# 2:         1        A Greer                    1
# 3:         1        J Adams                    1
# 4:         2   D Richardson                    1
# 5:         2        J Smith                    1
```

Assuming you're dealing with data like this:

```
mydf2 <- structure(list(author.ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), coauthor.names = structure(list(
        c("J Smith", "A Greer"), c("J Adams", "J Smith"), c("D Richardson", 
        "J Smith")), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("author.ID", "coauthor.names"
    ), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
mydf2
##   author.ID coauthor.names
## 1         1   J Smith,....
## 2         1   J Adams,....
## 3         2   D Richar....
```

... you can start with `listCol_l` (again from "splitstackshape") and then count in the same manner.

```
listCol_l(mydf2, "coauthor.names")[
  , list(collaboration.times = .N), .(author.ID, coauthor.names_ul)]
#    author.ID coauthor.names_ul collaboration.times
# 1:         1           J Smith                   2
# 2:         1           A Greer                   1
# 3:         1           J Adams                   1
# 4:         2      D Richardson                   1
# 5:         2           J Smith                   1
```

---

The "tidyverse" equivalents might be something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
# For a single character string as "coauthor.names"
mydf %>% 
  mutate(coauthor.names = lapply(strsplit(coauthor.names, ","), trimws)) %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(author.ID, coauthor.names) %>% 
  summarise(collaboration.times = n())

# If "coauthor.names" is already a `list`.
mydf2 %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(author.ID, coauthor.names) %>%
  summarise(collaboration.times = n())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can proceed!